# How to query nested arrays in mongoDB to find documents with elements that don't exist

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to make an aggregation query to **find all documents that do not contain a certain element**. It **needs to be an aggregation because I want to be able to edit the returned documents**. Eg. I only want to return some fields and I also want to be able to do a group on eg. the "producer" element.

I already tried practically all I can think of. I tried unwinding the arrays, but then I created even more documents where the element packagingInformation was mission than originally. I tried using $ne, $eq, $gt, $lte,.. to find the documents needed,... but they always return all documents because of the nested array structure.
$ArrayToObject didn't do the trick either for me.
I'm clueless on how to achieve this. The **tripple nested array structure** beats my imagination.

The only thing that returns me the wanted result is the following query:

```
db.product.find({
"json.productData.productInformation.details.packagingInformation": { $exists: false }
})
```

But this doesn't suffice since it's not an aggregate, thus it doens't allow me to continue to do queries with the results. And the $exists doesn't work in aggregates.

This is the JSON structure which I'm struggling with (dummy data).

```
{
    _id: 5ckflsmdk543klmf543klmtrkmgdfm,
    productNumber: 001,
    json: {
        productData: {
            productNumber: 001,
            producer: coca-cola,
            productInformation: [
                {
                    trackingInformation: {
                        lastUpdate: 01-01-12,
                        creationDate: 01-01-11
                    },
                    details: [
                        packagingInformation: [
                            quantity: 5,
                            size: 20cm                      
                        ],
                        productType: drinks,
                        otherMeaningLessInformation: whatever,
                        andEvenMoreInformationInArrays: [
                            andTheInformationGoesOn: wow,
                            andOn: nastyArrayStructures
                        ]
                    ]

                ]
            }       
        }

    }
}
```

The wanted result would be to return all the documents that do not contain the packagingInformation array or the packagingInformation.quantity element.

or even better, to return all documents but with an extra field: 
containsPackagingInformation: true/false. With false being the result of all documents that do not contain packagingInformation or packagingInformation.quantity.

Comment: what mongo version you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**`$exists DOES WORK in a aggregation.`**

`$exists` works the same way it works in `.find`

you can form a query like:

```
db.collection.aggregate({   $match: {
    $or: [
      {
        "json.productData.productInformation.details.packagingInformation.quantity": {
          $exists: false
        }
      },
      {
        "json.productData.productInformation.details.packagingInformation": {
          $exists: false
        }
      }
    ]   } })
```

Try this query [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Ruvq_gt8pQe) with dummy data

Comment: Seems to work indeed. It's because I was looking for a way to return all documents but with an extra field to match if the element was missing or not, that I missed this I think. But this will have to do for now. Thanks for the help!

Comment: is it also possible to instead of doing a $match, to do an "$addFields" which will add a field "containsPackagingInformation": true/false based on the existence of the fields "packagingInformation.quantity" or "packagingInformation"?

Comment: yes, you can use $addFields, in place of $match, but I count not use that in your case. Will try and update the ans.

Comment: niranjan, I managed to solve it on my own. Maybe not the most efficient way but it did the trick. 
I used the $match filter first, then I did an $addFields and then I stored the result in a new collection via a merge. I did this for all special filters/new fields I needed so that the newly made collection stored the documents needed with the new fields. Thanks again for showing me that $exists works for aggregates. The documentation made it seem like it didn't.